# Numerical integration of a three dimensional array

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, interpolation

I need to integrate a scalar valued function $f\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)$ where $\boldsymbol{x}$ is a three dimensional position vector; in other words:

$\int_{\Omega} f\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right) d^{3}\boldsymbol{x}$

The integration domain $\Omega$ is a a cube of side $L$.

The problem is that i don't have the analytical function but rather its values on a cartesian cubic grid $f \left(\boldsymbol{x_{\text{grid}}}\right)$.
Specifically, in my program $f \left(\boldsymbol{x_{\text{grid}}}\right)$ is a three dimensional array.

I was thinking to write a program in which i use Gaussian quadrature with $n$ points inside each element and interpolating the value of the function in the integration points and sum up the result from each element. This is however quite an intensive work, therefore my question is:

Is there a straightforward or easier way to perform such an integration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Generate an `InterpolatingFunction` using `Interpolation` and then use `NIntegrate`.  Alternatively, you could just `Sum` over `f`.

Comment: Are your samples evenly spaced inside $\Omega$?

Comment: By evenly spaced you mean equidistant one to each other? If so, yes

Comment: @bbgodfrey I don't think I can just sum up f, isn't there a Volume involved in each summation?

Comment: If the points are uniformly spaced, the volumes are the same for each point.  So, multiply the total by the volume for one point; i.e., the volume of the cube divided by the number of points.

Comment: Ok i got it, however what integration order has this kind of integration? and why would one use $n$ point Gaussian quadrature then?

Comment: For credible quadratures (e.g., splines), all orders give the same result when the points are uniformly spaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my Comment (and assuming uniform spacing of the data), consider the toy problem in 1-D:

```
f = Table[Sin[2 Pi ( i - .5)/10], {i, 10}]
```

Generating an `InterpolatingFunction` and then using `NIntegrate` yields:

```
g = Interpolation[f]
NIntegrate[g[x], {x, 1, 10}]
(* 3.3306690738754696*^-16 *)
```

Simply forming the Total yields the same result to machine precision.

```
Total[f]
(* 0. *)
```

This is not surprising, because using splines, etc cannot introduce more accurate information, because there is no more information.  (Mathematically, the splines, etc integrate to one.)

On the other hand, if the points are not evenly spaced, then `Interpolation` plus `NIntegrate` is a straightforward (but not the only) approach.

**Addendum**

I should add that for my toy problem the length associated with each point is one.  In other cases, just multiply by that unit length.

My point here is that using more elaborate integrating procedures accomplishes nothing for uniformly spaced points.

Comment: +1 the `Interpolation` approach is also useful for handling the edge conditions that arise depending on how your grid aligns with the region boundary.

Comment: actually my grid is perfectly aligned with the edge boundaries, because it is defined on the boundaries (a cube side divided in $N$ segments)

Comment: @george2079  You are correct.  However, summing the values of the points, weighted by the portion of their volumes that are inside the region of integration, should produce the same value.  And, thanks for the +1.

Comment: @user3810266  In that case, weight the points on surfaces by 1/2, on edges by 1/4, and on corners by 1/8.

Comment: @bbgodfrey do you have some reference for the fact that for an uniform grid different integration schemes have the same behavior? this also means that they converge to the exact value, as the elements shrink, with the same order?

Comment: @user3810266  Sorry, I have no reference.  But, try it yourself using `Interpolation` and `NIntegrate`.  Both have many options.  So long as you handle boundaries correctly, you should get the same results.